# Open a new tab for added links

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, hyperlinks

When we add a link to any answer or a user asks a question adding a link, our site should open a new page instead of launching the link on the same page.

Answer (score 5):

The *default* behaviour of links is to open in the same page; this is true for all websites. Because this is the default, people *expect* links to open in the same page; as a developer, you can override it, but only if you have very good reasons to do so. (I don't see any in your question right now.)

If you do want to open a link in a new page/tab, you can rely on your browser's or operation system's capability to do so. On macOS, it's holding down <kbd>Cmd</kbd> when clicking; on Windows hold down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>; other operation systems may be different. Right-clicking the link also works quite often.

Comment: @Yogi or middle/scroll click with a 3 button mouse.